# LinearGradient animation change isn't working / SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to animate the change of LinearGradients, but even when canUserPress changes, LinearGradients also change without animation.

I have already tried withAnimation {} - No result

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("streak") var streak = 0
    @AppStorage("streakHeight") var streakHeight = 0
    @AppStorage("canUserPress") var canUserPress = true
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
                LinearGradient (gradient: canUserPress ?
                  Gradient(colors: [Color("backNotAdded1"), Color("backNotAdded2")]) :
                  Gradient(colors: [Color("backAdded1"), Color("backAdded2")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2), value: canUserPress)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
   ...
```

Comment: Hi, how are you? When do you want it to animate? When a user clicks a button? or when the view appears?

Comment: hey, I am fine, tnx. I want it to animate when the canUserPress value is changing.

Answer (score 0):

So here's one way to do it:

> Note: this is not the best way to do it, but I find it very simple :)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("canUserPress") var canUserPress = false
    @State private var shouldAnimate = false
    
    let firstGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(.green), Color(.cyan)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
    let secondGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(.red), Color(.brown)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            if shouldAnimate { firstGradient }
            else { secondGradient }
            
            Button("Switch") { canUserPress.toggle() }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onChange(of: canUserPress) { _ in
            withAnimation {
                shouldAnimate = canUserPress ? true : false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I added another variable that checks whether it should animate based on `canUserPress` state.